# How many fights on Titan did Doctor Strange see out of the 14,000,605, that turned out negatively?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, avengers-endgame

I was wondering how many of the direct fights against Thanos on Titan turned out negatively out of the 14,000,605 that Doctor Strange saw?

Comment: We don't know what Strange saw. We do know that 14,000,604 resulted in the snapocalypse not being reversed. Note that he has powerful followers and acolytes who might have carried on his good works.

Comment: @Valorum well, to be fair, surely some of these had the Snap reversed. Just, you know, he killed everyone afterwards, so that's not the same Snapocalypse, pedantically speaking ;)

Comment: @Jenayah - what we don't know is whether the thing that Strange was preventing was the entire universe getting snapped or just reversing the original snap (Or something else entirely), nor how many universes had Thanos deciding that he needed to do some more killing

Comment: Presumably 14,000,604. If only 1 was successful, it is probably safe to assume all the others ended poorly.

Comment: I don’t think this is a great question, but I see no reason it’s POB.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, all we know is from the script in *Infinity War* which is as follows:

> Peter Parker: Hey, what was that?
>
> Doctor Strange: [panting] I went forward in time to view alternate
>   futures. To see all the possible outcomes of the coming conflict.
>
> Peter Quill: How many did you see?
>
> Doctor Strange: 14,000,605.
>
> Tony Stark: How many did we win?
>
> [Strange stares intently at Tony for a moment]
>
> Strange: [pause] One.

It's neither addressed what specifically Dr. Strange means by "the coming conflict" (although clearly he does not mean the initial battle with Thanos, as they lost that in the timeline he considers a "win") nor what specifically Tony meant by "win".  We're left to assume that all 14,000,604 of those that did not result in an Avengers "win" resulted in the fight on Titan turning out "negatively" (in the sense that Thanos neither died nor lost control of the Infinity Gauntlet and was able to snap).  It could easily be argued that in the "win" timeline of events, the battle on Titan "turned out negatively", so it's actually 100% of the time.

Comment: Personally, I'd expect that some of those millions of possibilities include a "win" (or a partial win) on Titan where Thanos then *later* manages to get all the stones, but that's just from the sheer number of them.